Enabling VSCode Java Testing via configuration
Is there any way to enable VSCode Java Testing (see second 8 to 12 in animation on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-testing#_enable-testing-and-adding-test-framework-jars-to-your-project) and choosing the framework by configuration (for example via settings.json - no clicking)?
